# Why isn't my JS pulling the value from the form properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

HTML in question is pretty simple:

`<form>
    <input type="text" name="locSearch" id="locSearch" />
    <button id="locSearchBtn"><i class="fa fa-search" id="search-icon"></i></button>
</form>`

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
getsWeather('seattle, wa', 'f');
$("#locSearchBtn").click(function() {
    getsWeather(document.getElementById('locSearch').value, 'f');
});
```

When I submit the form (either by pressing enter or by clicking the submit icon, the page reloads but with the default setting (i.e with 'Seattle, wa as the default argument for the getsWeather function). I need it to pull whatever is in the input box and use that as the argument in the getsWeather function but that currently isn't working.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more of the code to understand it

Comment: So question, do you find the page reload to be buggy or is that how the code is supposed to work? Because if its buggy, then you need to prevent the form from getting submitted. Otherwise all work gets reset

Comment: Is that because it reloads the entire script each time, even though I'm only asking it to reload it with the value that the user enters in the form?

Comment: @Jamiec Honestly, I'm not sure since I'm a bit of a beginner. I'm using the http://simpleweatherjs.com/ framework.

Comment: @pmath325 sorry, I misunderstood the question - ignore.

Comment: When a reload happens, the entire script and dom gets reset. However the values inside the form are submitted before the page is reloaded. 

Thus only the default values are loaded when page is refreshed and not the user added values. Unless you write the codes which loads user added values it will behave that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify the page, you need to prevent the form from being submitted when you click the button. Two ways to do that:

1. Add `return false` to the end of your `click` handler for the button. This will prevent form submission (if JavaScript is enabled on the client).
2. Add `type="button"` to the button so it's not a submit button anymore.

Ideally, you'd combine #1 with handling a form submission if the client doesn't have JavaScript enabled, to handle the small number of people who surf with JavaScript disabled via the form submission while handling JavaScript-enabled clients with the in-page update.

Comment: This worked for the button. How do I similarly add this to the input so that when the user presses enter the same thing happens?

Comment: @pmath325 similarly handle the `form` submit and return false too. Im sure @T.J. will update with details.

Comment: @Jamiec you guys are great. An explanation of why this works? What does submitting do that makes it so I need to have the return false?

Comment: @pmath325 the `return false` just stops the form from submitting.

Comment: @pmath325: As Jamie said, just add a `submit` handler to the form and use `preventDefault` (or return `false`) to prevent the form from submitting. Remember: Submitting the form refreshes the page, so that's why we prevent it from happening.